# Ayuda Condicional Javascript

Tags: javascript

Estoy muy, muy verde con JS y no encuentro una solución a mi duda con los condicionales `if` y `else`.

Tengo un botón `clickME` que en cada click me suma una cifra empezando por `0` y que me la muestra en el `div` `click`.

Hasta ahí todo bien, todo funciona correcto, pero lo que necesito hacer (y no me sale), es que si la cifra vale `0`, se muestre el `div` `singular`, y si la cifra es mayor a `1`, se muestre el `div` `plural`.

Lo que **NO** estoy haciendo bien está después de ( if (click == 0) ).

Esta es la parte que no me funciona, y he probado muchas variantes, pero no lo consigo.

```
var click=0;function clickME(){click += 1;document.getElementById("click").innerHTML=click};



if (click == 0) {
       document.getElementById("plural").style.display = "none"; 
       document.getElementById("singular").style.display = "block";
} else { 
       document.getElementById("plural").style.display = "block";
       document.getElementById("singular").style.display = "none";
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! no habras querido poner num === 0?

Comment: ¿Podrías pasarnos tú HTML también para que nos quede más fácil ayudarte?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! esto fue más o menos lo que te entendí; espero te sirva.

```js
var click=0;
function clickMe(){
  click += 1;
  document.getElementById("click").innerHTML = click;
  if (click === 1) { 
       document.getElementById("plural").style.display = "block";
       document.getElementById("singular").style.display = "none";
  };
};

if (click === 0) {
       document.getElementById("plural").style.display = "none"; 
       document.getElementById("singular").style.display = "block";
       document.getElementById("click").innerHTML = click;
}
```

```html
<div id="plural">Sección Plural</div>
<div id="singular">Sección Singular</div>

<button onclick="clickMe()">Click me!</button>

<div id="click"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Le hice algunos ajustes a tú codigo, lo que pasa es que sólo al momento de la carga verifica el estado de click cuando éste vale 0 en el siguiente click ya no pasa por verificación por lo tanto siempre muestra singular.
Por defecto se visualiza singular ya que siempre inicia con 0 la variable click;

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
            <title>
               Prueba Click
            </title>
            </script>
        </meta>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container text-center">
            <button id="clickButton" onclick="clickME()" type="button">
                Presiona click
            </button>
            <div id="texto">Singular</div>
            <div id="click"></p>
        </div>
        <script>
            var click=0;
            function clickME(){
             click += 1;
            document.getElementById("click").innerHTML=click;
            //Verifica el div a mostrar
            checkClick();
        };


  function checkClick() {
   if (click == 0) {
       document.getElementById("texto").textContent = "Singular";
   } else { 
        document.getElementById("texto").textContent = "Plural";
   }
  }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yo no dejaría el `style="display: none"`en el HTML, es una mala práctica en desarrollo.

Comment: Se veria mejor si en lugar de plural-singular, fuese par-impar, asi irian mostrando y ocultando continuamente los dos divs.

Comment: Le realice algunos ajustes para evitar el uso de display, lo de para e impar no estaría mal, pero para evitar confusiones hice las correcciones en base a su pregunta. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Creo que la estructura que se plantea es clara, se tiene que cargar la página web con una configuración inicial para los `divs`, otra que debería mantener los `divs` cuando se incrementa la variable a `uno` y luego está el caso cuando ya se trata con cifras de dos en adelante, para el plural.

A efecto de reutilizar código, se puede emplear una función de ayuda `actualizar_Div`, para que sea llamada de acuerdo a la casuística antes expuesta:

```
function actualizar_Div(act_plural, act_singular, msg=""){
  document.getElementById("plural").style.display = act_plural; 
  document.getElementById("singular").style.display = act_singular;
  document.getElementById("click").innerHTML = msg + click;
};
```

En tal sentido, el tercer parámetro es opcional porque este mensaje se concadena con la variable `click`, a efecto de indicar `Es 0, Es 1, Son 2, Son 3`, etc. si es que se requiere, esto como indiqué permite luego facilitar el mantenimiento del código. Por tanto, el código con sus respectivos comentarios quedaría así

```html
<html>
<body>

<div id="plural">.:Plural:.</div>
<div id="singular">.:Singular:.</div>

<button onclick="clickMe()">Click me!</button>

<div id="click"></div>

<script>

// Esta funcion actualizara la informacion de los div
// plural, singular y click dependiendo el caso donde se esta
function actualizar_Div(act_plural, act_singular, msg=""){
  document.getElementById("plural").style.display = act_plural; 
  document.getElementById("singular").style.display = act_singular;
  document.getElementById("click").innerHTML = msg + click;
};

// funcion para incrementar con el boton clickMe
var click = 0;      // Se Inicializa la variable click
function clickMe(){
  click += 1;      // Se incrementa la variable click
  
  if (click > 1) { 
    actualizar_Div("block", "none", "Son: ") // Plural
  } else { 
    actualizar_Div("none", "block", "Es: ")  // Singular
  };    
};

// Esta es la configuración inicial con la que se carga la página web
actualizar_Div("none", "block", "Es: ")

</script>

</body>
</html>
```